# Can you get drunk by just smelling an empty vodka bottle?

Tags: food-chemistry, alcohols

Is it possible to get drunk but just smelling an empty vodka bottle?

I got this empty *Skull Vodka* bottle from my mother which I thought looked really cool but it still smells a lot like vodka in it. I just want to make sure this will not affect me in any way.

Comment: No. You will be fine.

Comment: Hmm... was the bottle empty before or after you started "smelling"?

Comment: Wash it with water, and let it dry. It will not smell of vodka anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you could get drunk from smelling vodka. Like everything else that you can sense smelling, you uptake a little bit of the vodka (mainly the alcohol, i.e. ethanol component) by smelling it.

But those quantities are really minute. You would have to take a hot vodka vapour bath and stay in there for quite some time until you realise something. Remember that the amount you need to *drink* to get drunk varies, but is certainly somewhere above two shots. Now imagine how long it takes for ‘two shots’ worth of vodka had to condense in your nose and mouth from breathing — almost forever.

Comment: The vodka need not condense anywhere. It can be taken directly into the blood by the lungs. This is the basis of devices which create breathable mists of liquor, and it does not take long to get drunk from those.

Comment: @Nij I know, *condense* is the wrong word but I didn’t know a better one. Absorb maybe? Also, what kind of a throughput do those devices have?

Answer (score 2):

No. You won't get drunk from the scent of an empty bottle. If you could, it wouldn't be necessary to drink the vodka!